# Anti-Hermitian matrices and its diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As this is known that diagonal entries of anti-Hermitian matrices are imaginary? My question is can the diagonal entries also be complex in some special cases or not? In case a matrix has all properties of anti-Hermitian, but the diagonal entries are complex, what are the conditions for the diagonal entries such that the matrix becomes anti-hermitian or even hermitian. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community: It's a clear question. What is the problem with this?

Comment: We know that a matrix is anti-Hermitian iff the transpose and complex conjugate of it is the negative matrix. Apply this to a diagonal element and you will see that this rules out any other possibility that this diagonal element is purely imaginary or zero.